# proof problem of combination and summation

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}k\binom{n}{k}=0$$

[copied from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIQr4.png)

I don't know why  = 0?
Please answer my question
combination and summation therom is very hard to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

To prove this yourself (using analysis), start by differentiating

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

with respect to $x$. The result follows from a certain substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\ k\binom{n}{k}}&=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\\
&=n(1-1)^{n-1}\\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1+x)^n = \binom{n}{0} + x \binom{n}{1}+ \cdots +x^n \binom{n}{n}$ ----(1)

We need $ S= 1\binom{n}{1} -2 \binom{n}{2} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} n \binom{n}{n} $.

In equation (1), differentiate both sides with respect to $x$.

$n(1+x)^{n-1}=0+ 1 \binom{n}{1} +2x \binom{n}{2} + \cdots +n x^{n-1} \binom{n}{n}$ ----(2)

Now substitute $x=-1$ in equation (2).

$n(0)^{n-1}= 1 \binom{n}{1} -2 \binom{n}{2} + \cdots +n (-1)^{n-1} \binom{n}{n}$

$\Rightarrow$ $$S=0=1 \binom{n}{1} -2 \binom{n}{2} + \cdots +n (-1)^{n-1} \binom{n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k-1}k \binom{n}{k}$$